# How do I query the RViz Fixed Frame?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use the 2D Nav Goal tool of RViz, I get a position and orientation on /move_base_simple/goal.  How do I know which frame is used for the goal?  In other words, how do I know the currently-selected RViz Fixed Frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285040/how-do-i-query-the-rviz-fixed-frame?/) by [kylerlaird](https://answers.ros.org/users/23170/kylerlaird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2018-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh, geez...the frame_id is in the header of the goal.  Of course.

---

Originally posted by [kylerlaird](https://answers.ros.org/users/23170/kylerlaird/) with karma: 104 on 2018-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0